# I have created a new browse gallery added the lead in that in power app and trying to create the details and edit page in Power Apps

Tags: canvas, powerapps, dataverse, model-driven-app

I am trying to create the model driven app from Power App. I have already taken into account entity that already made 3 pages for me browse, details, and edit page. I am creating the same for lead entity in the same app I have already been able to make the browse page. For the details page I am not able to navigate to the details page with information.

What I have tried:

In the browse screen arrow, I have written this

```
Navigate(DetailScreen2, ScreenTransition.None, {SelectedItem: BrowseGallery2.Selected})
```

and in the details ecreen for every field, I am writing this in the text as:

For example:

```
SelectedItem.'Lead Id'
```

It's navigating to the details screen but not showing the values.

**Note:**
Select (Parent) in the arrow of the browse gallery is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Items property of the Form should be set as 'SelectedItem' as per the argument passed to another screen.

Also, Select(Parent) means if your control is within a parent then Parent's OnSelect property will be triggered.